# Magneto2 : How to show related products to right side in product view page

Tags: magento-2.1, theme

How can I show related products to right side section of the product view page?

I want to show 3 related products in  right side section i wrote

```
      <referenceContainer name="right">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
      </referenceContainer>
```

but its not working

Comment: Your prodcut page is 3cloumn page?

Comment: no, 1 column layout

Comment: right referncecontainer is not working for 1 column layout, You have to use 2 columns-right or 3 column layout to set in right section Otherwise you have to some fixed using css.

Comment: Magento 2 haven't container with name "right" or "left", but you can use "div.sidebar.additional" or "sidebar.additional"